# List/Library level custom alert template

Tags: email, alert

All, I am following the instructions from here ([custom alert template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx)) to set custom alert template for a list/library. I have a document library for which I would like custom alert email. Following are the steps I did:

- Copy OOB alerttemplate.xml and name it alerttemplateTest.xml
- Modified the existing template `SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary`
- Added new template to new alerttemplateTest.xml (`SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary.Test`)
- Ran the stsadm command:

  ```
   STSADM -o updatealerttemplates -url <http://urlname> -filename <your working copy filename>
  ```
- Updated `list.AlertTemplate` to the new template (`SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary.Test`) for "Shared Documents" within a site through object model

For all the document libraries, the alert email reflect the changes i made in  `SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary`. But the emails for Shared Documents I set to `SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary.Test` doesnt contain the changes. The emails contain changes for `SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary`. Through the object model, i can see that "Shared Documents" has the correct template, which is `SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary.Test`. Did i miss anything?

I appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be any one of a hundred issues with custom alerts, but one of the landmines is that existing alerts on the list still refer to the original template name of "SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary".  Try creating a new alert and testing that.

If that works, then you will need to modify your code a bit to update existing alerts to use the new template.

Comment: I removed the existing subscription and created a new one and the alert emails picked up the right template! Thanks for your help! FYI for others, I have subscribed to the list before I updated the alert template and expected the existing subscription will use the new template. But the users will have to unsubscribe and resubscribe to get the emails with new alert template.